# How resolve undefined reference to vtable in c++ on QT

Tags: c++, qt, extend

i have `Ubuntu 14.04` , `C++` , `QT`  , 
I will `extend` the class `QPushbutton` , and i will to make a new `Slot` 
I do :

```
#include<QApplication>
#include<QDialog>
#include<QLabel>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include<QVBoxLayout>
#include<iostream>
#include<QWidget>
#include<QPushButton>
#include <QThread>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QSplitter>
#include<QAbstractButton>
using namespace std;




class bot :  public QPushButton  {
   Q_OBJECT;

 public slots:
    void txt() {
        setText("hi");
         }


};


int main(int a , char * b[])
{
    QApplication application(a,b);
    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton();
    bot *l = new bot();
    button->setFixedSize(100,100);
    l->setText("sssssssssssssss");

    QVBoxLayout *ll  = new QVBoxLayout;
    ll->addWidget(l);
    ll->addWidget(button);
    QWidget x ;
    x.setLayout(ll);
    x.show();
    QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), l , SLOT( txt()) );

    return application.exec();


}
```

The Problem is :

> /home/user/untitled6/sd.cpp:18: error: undefined reference to `vtable
>   for bot'

how resolve the problem ???

my file.pro is :

```
SOURCES += \
    sd.cpp
QT += widgets

FORMS += \
    form.ui
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, errors like that can be resolved by running QMake. Anytime you create a new class that derives from `QObject`, Qt's model meta-object compiler (MOC) needs to auto-generate the code for the meta-class of the new class -- QMake ensures that this happens.

If you are using Qt Creator, just select `Run qmake` from the `Build` menu.

You may also have to run `Clean project X` or `Clean all`, also found in the `Build` menu.

The MOC can be temperamental, so you need to do the following:

- Move your `QObject`-derived class into a separate source and header file (In your case, create `bot.h` and `bot.cpp`, and move the class code there)
- Separate declaration and definition of your slot code (define `txt` as `bot::txt` in `bot.cpp`)

The MOC generates a corresponding meta-class file (`moc_bot.cpp`, in your case), and sometimes gets confused when there are multiple `QObject`-derived classes in one file. Best practice is to use one header and one source file for each `QObject`-derived class.

If all else fails, you may need to delete the `.pro.user` file for your project, and exit and restart Qt Creator. Then from `Build` menu, choose `Clean all`, `Run qmake`, `Rebuild All`.

Comment: It remained the same problem !

Comment: @SalamBoy Try cleaning the project, see edit

Comment: I will ,     
 
It remained the same problem

Comment: Yeah  Thanks Tony , But why do I have to put the file in new Head ?

Comment: @SalamBoy Glad it worked, it's a quirk of the moc, see edit

Comment: how modife th quirk of the moc ?

Comment: A "quirk" is a strange behavior, almost a bug. Try the latest edit